# Add A Table Row With Ajax Results

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, dom

I have a function that takes the values returned from an ajax call and adds a row to a table that is defined in the json values, but I don't think it is fetching the table correctly. Is there anything special I need to be doing? I know the data['table_name'] variable does have the correct value in it.

Here is the code I have.

```
function ajaxSuccess () {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var elementObj = document.getElementById(data['table_name']);

                var i = elementObj.size() + 1;
                elementObj.append('<tr><td>Date</td><td>Name</td><td>' + data['new_comment'] + '</td></tr>');
                i++;
                return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct.

You have js variable `var elementObj = document.getElementById(data['table_name']);`

And you use jquery `append()`.

Try `var elementObj = $("#"+data['table_name']);` instead.

Also check console for errors, you are probably receiving this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'append'
```

p.s. you can also try this:

```
$(elementObj).append('<tr><td>Date</td><td>Name</td><td>' + data['new_comment'] + '</td></tr>');
```

without rewriting var elementObj to jquery variable.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification I as able to get it working with the js var row = elementObj.insertRow(0); command